# Get service and model from another service (module) Gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea, module

The essence of the problem.
I have several services.

1. Starter - to start and stop the rest
2. Service_for_calc - for calculating some operations
3. Service_sample - service for example
4. Common_Service-a service for storing models and utils[image]

According to my idea, I will run a starter that will run the rest of the services. Each service will have the same endpoints and models. For example, take the WhoIs functionality.
Each service must tell you who it is.
I don't want to create a model and @Service in every service (module).
I want to create this in Common_service and just import the ready-made logic.
I tried to do this via gradle
to do this in the root settings. gradle I wrote

```
include 'Service_for_calc'
include 'Common_Service'
include 'Service_sample'
include 'Starter '
```

and in the service (module) I prescribed it

```
implementation project(':hub.common')
```

But I ran into some problem, I can't even describe it clearly, because each time it looked different, but here are the errors that I got when trying to work this way

1. The module does not see classes from common or does not see the package (despite the fact that the IDE began to suggest them to me)
2. Some kind of trouble started with the dependency (specifically, Spring dependencies will start working every other time)
3. Sometimes gradle did not see and threw an error on the implementation project (': hub. common'), with the error that there is no such project ( the name was correct)
4. After I removed the dependencies, reloaded Gradle and installed it, it worked, but when I tried to open this project on someone else's computer, point 1 was repeated

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or maybe I shouldn't do it at all.
Is this approach practiced? Was it worth doing it via gradle or should I try it via classpath?
Is it worth doing whole services in a common project?

I will be glad to have a detailed answer!

Comment: If there is a multi-module project with a similar structure, preferably with a stack "java and spring" , I will be happy with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting settings.gradle in every project except the root one!

Answer (score 1):

You have module name conflict, if you have a module named `include 'Common_Service'` then you should `implementation project(':Common_Service')`

PS: [Here](https://github.com/GrinRus/rest-docs-demo) git repo with multi-module, maybe this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.4.4'
        dependencyManagementVersion = '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:${dependencyManagementVersion}"
    }
}

allprojects {
    group = 'omegabi.back.hub'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    sourceCompatibility = 11

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }
}


project(':hub.sample_service') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':hub.common_service')
    }
}
```